# Area of figure traced by translating a curve

Tags: geometry

The is a question in elementary geometry I happened upon. A curve of length $K$ is translated a distance of $L$, and traces out some area $A$, shaded below:
[image]

If we drop a perpendicular from $ab$ to $cd$, the length of the perpendicular is $H$. The problem is find the shaded area.

I believe $A$ is $L\times H$, but a friend (minoring in mathematics) claims it's $L\times K$, and her argument is that if you were to "straighten" the purple ribbon, it would be a rectangle of $L$ by $K$.

I feel this is such a common problem there has to be a webpage somewhere explaining this, or perhaps there is a similar question already asked here on Math SE that I haven't found?

Comment: If you think of this as a Riemann sum it should be clear that you're right.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle

Comment: Ask your friend to consider the case when the curve is a straight line not perpendicular to $ab$. What does she think the area of a parallelogram is?

Comment: Draw lines from a to c and from b to d - the not shaded area equals the shaded area, which means that the rectangle (you use) has the area of the shaded area! So you are right.